# 3N-dimensional integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to compute a multidimensional integral with a variable number of dimensions.

The integral is as follows:
$$
\int d^{3N}\!p~e^{-\frac{\beta}{2m}\vec p^2}.
$$

I have tried this

```
Integrate[e^(-a*{p1,p2,p3}^2),{{p1,p2,p3}^N,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

but it's not working at all. I guess I have to determine the vector before, or?

More generally, to what extent can *Mathematica* compute such integrals for arbitrary $N$ and arbitrary integrands in place of $e^{-\frac{\beta}{2m}\vec p^2}$?

Comment: `Integrate` only supports integrating with respect to scalar variables, i.e. you need to integrate by the *components* of the vector.  See the doc page on `Integrate` on how, and pay attention to spelling of names and capitalisation.  (`Integrate`, `E^x`, and don't use `N` as a variable because it's a built-in symbol)

Comment: You don't need Mathematica to compute this. Switch to the generalized spherical coordinates and integrate over `r` and the angles. This is exmplained in many texts on Quantum Field Theory, look up dimensional regularization.

Comment: Actually, in this case, it is even much simpler, your integral factorizes into a product of simple integrals.

Comment: I have voted to reopen because I believe there is a legitimate interpretation of the question, as suggested by my edit of it (and I recall seeing similar issues raised on this site but do not recall seeing a general answer).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'm fairly sure dimensional reguralization isn't necessary for multidimensional gaussian integrals :) It factorizes, also, you can go to generalized spherical coordinates. However this seems to really be asking "how do I set up multidimensional integrals". In any case I think the real answer is "you're better off with some sort of monte carlo scheme for large N and arbitrary integrands"

Comment: @acl I agree, I made a note on that myself, right below my first suggestion. I think this was just a reflex - I've done too many of those diagrams with dimensional regularization at the time (actually, I personally dislike it, because it is unphysical and regularizes both UV and IR, which is rather non-sensical given that UV and IR phenomena are often utterly different, except possibly for the case of anomalies. I prefer Pauli-Villars). But that's all in the past, now I am just a programmer, one of many.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin right sorry, I somehow missed your second clarification (and yes I've also done far too many such integrals and didn't like them...)

Comment: @acl Also, when I referred to the dimensional regularization, I only meant that many textbooks which cover it describe the generalized spherical coordinates in some detail. I did not mean to suggest actually using the regularization, since the integral is convergent.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin good advice then, it should be described clearly there.

Answer (score 12):

For integrands where Fubini's Theorem is applicable (and that would be the great majority), we may iterate the integral.  The following solution--intended to work with fixed limits of integration in all dimensions--does this with two definitions: one to perform the integration over the last variable and another to get everything started.

```
integrateND[f_, limits_] /; Length[limits] > 1 := Module[{x, n = Length[limits]},
   Integrate[integrateND[f[##, x] &, Most[limits]], {x, limits[[-1, 1]], limits[[-1, 2]]}]];
integrateND[f_, limits_]  := Module[{x}, Integrate[f[x], {x, limits[[1, 1]], limits[[1, 2]]}]];
```

The arguments of `integrateND` are a function of an arbitrary number $n$ variables and a list of $n$ limits (lower and upper, each given as a list).  For example, the integration in the question with $N=2$ (which is a six-dimensional integral) can now be performed as

```
With[{n = 2}, 
 Assuming[\[Beta] / (2 m) > 0, 
  integrateND[Exp[-\[Beta] / (2 m) {##}.{##}] &, ConstantArray[{-Infinity, Infinity}, 3 n]]]]
```

> $\frac{8 \pi ^3 m^3}{\beta ^3}$

High-dimensional multiple integrals should be invoked judiciously: they can take a very long time to compute or not be computable at all.

Answer (score 12):

Although the original question is a little too narrow, I'm going to interpret it as asking about general multidimensional integrals in which Gaussians appear together with arbitrary factors in the integrand:

$$\iiint f(\,\vec{r}\,)\,\exp(\,-\frac{1}{2}\vec{r}^T\Sigma^{-1}\vec{r}\,)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

Here $\Sigma^{-1}$ could be a symmetric positive definite matrix, or in the simplest case just $\sigma^2$ times the identity matrix. The dimension can be anything, but here I'll just specialize to three.

Then you may be interested in this observation which speeds up such integrals tremendously in comparison with straightforward multiple integration:

**Edit: An integrand that doesn't factor**

Start by defining the Gaussian in three dimensions:

```
f = PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 
    0}, \[Sigma] IdentityMatrix[3]], {x, y, z}]
```

> $\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}
>    \left(-\frac{x^2}{\sigma
>    }-\frac{y^2}{\sigma
>    }-\frac{z^2}{\sigma }\right)}}{2
>    \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2} \sqrt{\sigma
>    ^3}}$

Try the following as a triple integral:

```
Timing[Integrate[
  Integrate[Integrate[
    (x^2 + y^3)/(1 + z^2)
      f, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {y, -Infinity, \
Infinity}], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]
```

> $\left\{1.48519,\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\sqrt{\frac{
>    \pi }{2}} e^{\frac{1}{2 \sigma
>    }} \sqrt{\sigma ^3}
>    \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{
>    2} \sqrt{\sigma
>    }}\right)}{\sigma },\Re(\sigma
>    )>0\right]\right\}$

Now do the same using `Expectation`, keeping in mind the different normalization of the result:

```
Timing[Expectation[(x^2 + y^3)/(
  1 + z^2), {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, \[Sigma] IdentityMatrix[3]]]
 ]
```

> $\left\{0.775868,\sqrt{\frac{\pi
>    }{2}} e^{\frac{1}{2 \sigma }}
>    \sqrt{\sigma }
>    \text{erfc}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{
>    2} \sqrt{\sigma
>    }}\right)\right\}$

So the result is obtained about twice as fast using `Expectation`.

**Fourier transforms as a special case**

My initial example was the Fourier transform of a Gaussian,

$$\iiint \exp(- i\, \vec{k}\cdot \vec{r}\,)\,\exp(\,-\frac{1}{2}\vec{r}^T\Sigma^{-1}\vec{r}\,)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

where the speed advantage of `Expectation` compared to multiple `Integrate` with infinite integration boundaries is more significant than above:

```
Expectation[
 Exp[-I {kx, ky, kz}.{x, y, z}], {x, y, z} \[Distributed] 
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, σ IdentityMatrix[3]]]
```

> $e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sigma 
>    \left(\text{kx}^2+\text{ky}^2+\text{kz}^2\right)}$

This works for *symbolic* integrands (note I didn't specify a value for $\sigma$ or the components of $\vec{k}$), and you don't have to specify the list of integration boundaries explicitly either. The timing for the above is about 7 times faster than doing the calculation using three nested `Integrate`s, where I also have to add assumptions for the parameters (specifically $\sigma>0$, $\vec{k}$ real).

Although my initial claim is correct that this is faster than the straightforward triple integral, one can do a lot better in this special case by just using `FourierTransform` directly:

```
Timing[FourierTransform[f, {x, y, z}, {kx, ky, kz}]]
```

> $\left\{0.007332,\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2} \sigma 
>    \left(\text{kx}^2+\text{ky}^2+\text{kz}^2\right)}
>    }{2 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2} \left(\frac{1}{\sigma
>    }\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{\sigma ^3}}\right\}$

Interestingly, though, we can *even* beat this really fast result using the multinormal distribution again:

```
Timing[CharacteristicFunction[
  MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, \[Sigma] IdentityMatrix[3]], {kx,
    ky, kz}]
 ]
```

> $\left\{0.000185,e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\text{kx}^2
>    (-\sigma )-\text{ky}^2 \sigma -\text{kz}^2 \sigma
>    \right)}\right\}$

**Conclusion**

For Gaussian integrals over all space (or momentum space, as in the question), the  approach using `MultinormalDistribution` is complementary to whuber's solution: general Gaussian integrals can be evaluated by using `Expectation` and similar tools for probability distributions, such as `CharacteristicFunction`.

Comment: For this problem,  we can use the Expection and distribution to calculate it. But it is still not fast for the large dimension and complex gaussian form. Because we usuall have the anlytical result for the Gaussian integrals, can we find some package for dealing with this kind of problem?

Comment: @Orders I added some more speed comparisons. I would say that the package you're looking for is probably just the set of statistical capabilities built into *Mathematica*. Maybe there's other packages thatI'm not aware of.

Answer (score 6):

For your particular example, you could use `FullRegion[n]` as the integration domain:

```
Integrate[Exp[-(β/(2m)) p.p], p ∈ FullRegion[6], Assumptions->β>0 && m>0]
```

> (8 m^3 π^3)/β^3

which is the same as whuber's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing from @carl's answer, we can do it for a few dimensions and 'guess' the trend.

```
tt = Table[
  Integrate[Exp[-(\[Beta]/(2 m)) p.p], p \[Element] FullRegion[i], 
   Assumptions -> \[Beta] > 0 && m > 0], {i, 2, 10}]
```

[image]
it seems this reproduces it quite well:

```
tt2 = Table[(\[Beta]/(2 m \[Pi]))^(-i/2) , {i, 2, 10}];
tt/tt2 // PowerExpand;
```

{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

So the answer seems to be for arbitrary $N$

```
((\[Beta]/(2 m \[Pi]))^(-N/2))
```

Of course this is not a proof ;-)