# Integration over a convex combination of a region: $\int_{\Omega} (w_1 z_1 + w_2 z_2)^{1-\sigma} d (z_1, z_2)$ where $\Omega = \{ z_1 + z_2 = 1\}$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

Take $w,z\in R^{n}$.  I am interested in integrating (as generically if possible) 
$$\int_{\Omega}(w \cdot z)^{1-\sigma} d z$$
Where the domain of $\Omega$ is $1$ dimension, and includes the convex combinations of $z$.  i.e. $\Omega \equiv \{z | \sum z = 1 \}$

Obviously, for $n=2$, this is easy to rearrange:
$$\int_{0}^{1} \left(w_1 z_1 + w_2 (1-z_1)\right) d z_1$$
$$ = \frac{w_2^{2-\sigma} - w_1^{2-\sigma}}{(\sigma - 2)(w_1 - w_2)}$$

And the mathematica code is:

```
Integrate[(w[1] z[1] + w[2] (1 - z[1]))^(1 - σ), {z[1], 0, 1}] // FullSimplify
```

But it is a little harder to cheat like this as $n$ gets larger, and I am hoping for more general patterns.  How would I set up the simple $n=2$ example using the convex combination directly?  I tried things like:

```
 Integrate[(w[1] z[1] + w[2] z[2])^(1 - σ), {z[1], 0, 1}, {z[2], 1 - z[1], 1 - z[1]}] // FullSimplify
```

Integration over a convex combination of a region: $\int_{\Omega} (w_1 z_1 + w_2 z_2)^{1-\sigma} d (z_1, z_2)$ where $\Omega = \{ z_1 + z_2 = 1\}$

...but I couldn't get them to work.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33051/how-do-i-generate-arbitrarily-many-integration-bounds)   will help with generating limits and dummy variables. I'm afraid I don't understand the question enough to help with the integrand.

Comment: Thanks.  Alas, the link you have doesn't seem to have the bounds dropping a dimension, as my example does.

Comment: Well, we can always modify that example. Do you have an equation for the limits? Maybe you could throw a Boole[Total[z]==1] in the integrand.

Comment: Along the same lines as @TimothyWofford, you might try the appropriate DiracDelta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we enumerate the all the distinct edges in a fully connected graph (an equivalent problem, I believe). Then we parameterize the edge by `{t,0,1}` assuming that the direction of integration doesn't matter. Then we integrate over each edge and total the integrals.

```
n = 4;
z[n_] := ToExpression[ToString[z] <> ToString[n]]
edges=Union@Map[Sort, Permutations[Array[z, n], {2}]];
lines = ReplaceAll[Array[z, n], {#[[1]] -> t, #[[2]] -> (1 - t)}] & /@ edges;
(* h[x_]:=x^(1-σ) *)
g[line_]:= h[Array[w, n].line]
Total@Map[Integrate[g[#], {t, 0, 1}] &, lines]
```

**What follows below was an initial answer based on a misunderstanding. I am leaving it because it may be a useful reference.**

If I understand correctly, then the limits can be assigned as follows

```
n = 2;
f[1] := {z[1], 0, 1}
f[n_] := {z[n], 0, 1 - z[n - 1]};
bounds = Array[f, n];
Integrate[(Array[w, n].Array[z, n])^(1 - σ),Sequence @@ bounds]
```

For those who program better than I do, how can we make this faster? for `n=3` I get 4.13607 seconds!

```
n=3;
bounds = Array[f, n];
Integrate[g[Sequence @@ bounds[[All, 1]]], Sequence @@ bounds]
```

This brings it down to 2.6 seconds for `n=3`.

```
z[n_] := ToExpression[ToString[z] <> ToString[n]]
```

Comment: Very helpful.  But is the first one doing a triangular domain of dimension $n$ rather than of a 1 dimension subspace of the convex combinations??  The `Boole[Total[z]==1]` mentioned above seems to be the right domain choice

Comment: @jlperla, Aahh, I see. I did a `RegionPlot` of `Boole[Total[z]==1]` and misinterpreted the triangle as the volume underneath, rather than the edges. So, we need to parameterize the edge of this triangle, and do a single integration over the parameter? How many edges are there for n=4,5,etc.?

Comment: @jlperla, I have edited to integrate over the edges.

Comment: Thank you, I think that does it.

Comment: @TimothyWofford Could you please complete your answer with a definition for line? Regards.

Comment: @chris As it appears, `line` is a placeholder variable. Semantically it is one of the elements in the `lines` list. I went ahead and changed `Set` to `SetDelayed` to make this explicit.

Comment: @TimothyWofford would you mind adding a working example please?

Comment: @chris `w[n_]:=1; h[x_]:=1;` gives you the total (number/length?) of edges.